# Please clear up this misunderstanding I have involving limits.

Tags: limits

I have passed the calc sequence, and thought that I understood things.  But I have trouble with limits now and again.  From the way I understand it, the 'best' way to evaluate a limit, is to evaluate the expression at the number in the limit.  In that way it's not only a limit, but an algebraic expression (so, I think, the need for limits goes away entirely, superseded by accuracy.)

But then I see something like $\lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$.  Now, I think in my mind 'the best way to evaluate this is just to plug in $2$'  But it doesn't work that way, as the limit is $4$, and if I plug in, the answer is $0/0$.  I think that people here, with their natural talent in math, can perceive where my train of thought is going wrong, and correct me.  Please!

Comment: If you can simplify the function, do so *before* attempting to plug in.

Comment: @Bye_World - I've seen (from Wolfram) that simplifying does this.  But, to my obviously misled intuition, it should be the same either way (the same expression should evaluate to the same result, regardless of whether or not it's simplified?)

Comment: @horsehair It is not defined at that point. What you are doing is evaluating at the point when it is not defined.

Comment: @horsehair It generally will be -- unless you get something like $0/0$ or $\infty / \infty$.  These are called "indeterminate forms" and don't tell you what the limit actually is.  If you plug in and get one of these, you have to try something else (like maybe simplification or l'Hopital's rule).  Also, simplifying an expression before plugging in values generally makes evaluating it easier, so you might as well make it standard practice to start with that.

Comment: Both of you - Thanks!

Comment: Easy phrase to remember: "the limit of a quotient is the quotient of the limits provided that the denominator is not zero."

Comment: @Christopher I feel that's be much easier to remember if you could make it rhyme...

Comment: @horsehair I think this post gives you a good answer: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503544/indeterminate-form-from-calculus

Comment: Keep in mind that a _function_ is completely different from an _expression_ - e.g., you could have $f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ if $x\neq 2$ and $f(2)=54301$; that's a totally legitimate function, but plugging in 2 to it gives you the value $54301$, which clearly isn't the same as the limit.  Instead, you want to plug in a sequence of values steadily _closer_ to 2 but not equal to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that 
$$
  \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{x^2-4}{x-2} \;=\; 
  \lim_{x\to 2} \frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2} \;=\; 
  \lim_{x\to 2} (x+2) \;=\; 
  4
$$
The idea is that $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ has a **point discontinuity** at $x=2$: it has a little hole there because we can't divide by zero. Other than that little hole, the expressions $\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$ and $(x+2)$ are the same. We can see in each of them that the limit as $x$ approaches $2$ is $4$.

Also, in response to what you said

> From the way I understand it, the 'best' way to evaluate a limit, is to evaluate the expression at the number in the limit. In that way it's not only a limit, but an algebraic expression (so, I think, the need for limits goes away entirely, superseded by accuracy).

I see what you are saying, but I would phrase it a little differently. In the cases where you can just evaluate a $\lim_{x\to n}f(x)$ by plugging $n$ into $f(x)$, I would word it as "the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ approaches $n$ *happens* to be the same as the value of $f$ at $n$".

Comment: I hope I'm not so far off the original question as to wander into irrelevance but -- isn't the left hand expression equal to the right?  And since we have 'x' to plug in, shouldn't they be equivilant?

Comment: @horsehair, they are *super close* to being equivalent. The only difference is the little blip at $x=2$. This is a quirk of mathematics that is a consequence of the "*you cannot divide by zero*" rule.

Comment: Understood, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Typically limits are used when the expression isn't defined where you want to evaluate it, so just plugging the limit in, will rarely do anything.

But in cases like the one you mention, you can rewrite the expression so something that is defined at the limit, and **then** you can plug in the limit.

What you need to observe is that $x^2-4 =(x-2)(x+2)$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: *why* do we take limits?

If you can just plug a number in an expression, why do we use $\epsilon-\delta$ to define what a limit is?

Take $f(x) = x^2$

Here the best way to evaluate a limit is just to plug the number in, as you say; this is because $$\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0)$$ in every point $x_0$. Functions with this property are called *continuous* and you can just plug the numbers in to find the result (that is, calculate $f(x_0)$)

The problem is that sometimes the value $f(x_0)$ is *not* defined..

Take $f(x) = \frac {x^2}{x}$. What is $f(0)$? It's not defined.
But if you draw the function $f(x)$ , [you can see](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E2%2Fx) that near $0$ the function is basically $0$. So even though it does not exists in $0$, in a certain sense for values of $x$ very close to $0$ the function is equal to $0$.

The precise way of formulating this intuition is to define what a limit is! And you find out that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = 0$ as we wanted.

---

Now how do we find limit, in practice?

As you said, if you just plug $2$ in your function it will be undefined.

But when we calculate limit we only care about what happens *near* the point (in your case $2$) not *at* the point.

Since your function is equal to $x+2$ for every point $x \neq 2$, you can just plug $2$ in this simpler expression to find out that the limit is $4$

Answer (score 0):

The limit of a function $f$ at the point $a$ is *not* the value of $f$ at $a$. Those are two different things. It just so happens that for many functions, they are equal.

The limit of a function is the value that the function goes towards as you approach that point. That doesn't necessarily tell you anything about the value of the function *at* that point.

In your case, you have a function which has a certain limit as $x$ approaches $2$, yet which isn't even defined at $x=2$. This isn't paradoxical because nobody ever said that $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ and $f(a)$ had to be the same every time. Only some of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is a very very non rigours approach some people may kill me, but

I will try to make this approach like this, you said why the function doesn't approaches same value.

$f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$

We are evaluating this at $x=2$,

$f(x)=\frac{2^2-2^2}{2-2}$

It can be rewritten as,

$f(x)=\frac{(2+2)2(1-1)}{2(1-1)}$
$f(x)=4 \frac{0}{0}$

So, the $0's$ cancels each other and yay same result, now why is this wrong?

Because we can write $\frac{0}{0}=\frac{100-100}{10-10}=10 $ or any other value think of! , that's why the above solution is not correct!

What limit does?

Well essentially it redefines $0$ a variable $h$ which $\to $ $0$ or any variable which introduces the undefined things.

Now, we **do not** say this variable is 0, but it goes to 0 and never actually touches it. In the enlightenment of this new definition we will re-evaluate our function using this new definition. In your function it is $\lim_{x \to 2}(x-2)=\lim_{h \to 0} h$

$L=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x+2)(x-2)}{(x-2)}$

$L= \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{(x+2)}{1} $

$L=4$

And there we didn't have to go through any undefined nasty 0 and problem solved. You can say limit saved the day!